# Entity Behavior in Entity Framework is very strange

Tags: .net, entity-framework, repository

I'm using EF 4.1 and I have a Edit method in repository:

```
public virtual void Edit(TEntity entity)
{
   this.DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

This method don't update my aggregates, I have this entity:

```
public class Credencial : Entity
{
    private IList<Perfil> _perfis;

    public Credencial()
    {
        Status = Status.Inativo;
    }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Perfil> Perfis
    {
        get { return _perfis ?? (_perfis = new List<Perfil>()); }
        set { _perfis = value; }
    }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public byte StatusId
    {
        get { return (byte)Status; }
        set { Status = (Status)value; }
    }
    public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }

    public string Senha { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to update **Perfis** property like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeveEditarUsuarioNoRepositorio()
{
    Usuario usuario = _usuarioRepository.GetById(1);

    usuario.Credencial.Perfis = null;

    usuario.Nome = "Samla Peidorreira";
    usuario.Email = "samlapeidanascalca@samlapeidanascalca.com";
    usuario.DataNascimento = new DateTime(1988, 11, 19, 4, 23, 54, 0);
    usuario.Sexo = (Sexo)Convert.ToByte(Sexo.Masculino);
    usuario.Telefone = null;
    usuario.Credencial.Status = (Status) Convert.ToByte(Status.Ativo);

    //Here I want to replace Perfis, but it only add one more
    usuario.Credencial.Perfis = new List<Perfil>() { new Perfil() { Nome = "Fotografos", DataEdicao = new DateTime(1996, 2, 1, 12, 15, 42, 27), Deletado = true, Status = false, Tipo = 3 } };

    usuario.Credencial.NomeUsuario = "samlapeidanascalca";
    usuario.Credencial.Senha = "samlacagona";

    _usuarioRepository.Edit(usuario);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    Usuario usuarioEditado = _usuarioRepository.GetById(1);

    Assert.AreEqual("Samla Peidorreira", usuarioEditado.Nome);
    Assert.AreEqual("samlapeidanascalca@samlapeidanascalca.com", usuarioEditado.Email);
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(1988, 11, 19, 4, 23, 54, 0), usuarioEditado.DataNascimento);
    Assert.AreEqual(Sexo.Masculino, usuarioEditado.Sexo);
    Assert.AreEqual(null, usuarioEditado.Telefone);
    Assert.AreEqual(Status.Ativo, usuarioEditado.Credencial.Status);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, usuarioEditado.Credencial.Perfis.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(5, usuarioEditado.Credencial.Perfis[0].Id);
    Assert.AreEqual("samlapeidanascalca", usuarioEditado.Credencial.NomeUsuario);
    Assert.AreEqual("samlacagona", usuarioEditado.Credencial.Senha);
}
```

What happen is the repository add one more **Perfil** in my entity. I don't want to add one more, I want to replace.

**Update:**

I found a question with same problem: [Update method for generic Entity framework repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851147/update-method-for-generic-entity-framework-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting state of the entity has no effect on the state of its relations. If you want to replace data in `Perfil` you must handle it separately and set its correct state. It is [a feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326) (it is about ObjectContext API but the same is true or worse with DbContext API).

Comment: OMG, are you sure? Why EF do it with me? You not think EF is implemented in a wrong way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. Once you are working with detached entities you must manually set state of each entity or relation once you attache them to the context.