# EF 4.1 - Update Properties On Child Collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, automapper

I have searched hi and low and I am stuck here.

I am using EF 4.1 in an MVC3 app, with the Service/Repository/UnitOfWork pattern and AutoMapper to map my models and entities.

So I have a really basic situation; I have a collection of `ChildProducts` that have a collection of `PriceTiers`.

My view models look like this:

**AddEditChildProductModel**

```
public class AddEditChildProductModel
    {
        #region "Fields/Properties"
        public ActionType ActionType { get; set; }
        public string FormAction { get; set; }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public decimal Cost { get; set; }
        public decimal MSRP { get; set; }
        public decimal RetailPrice { get; set; }

        public int Servings { get; set; }
        public decimal Weight { get; set; }

        public bool Display { get; set; }
        public int DisplayIndex { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<AddEditPriceTierModel> PriceTiers { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region "Constructor(s)"

        #endregion

        #region "Methods"

        #endregion
    }
```

**AddEditPriceTierModel**

```
public class AddEditPriceTierModel
    {
        #region "Fields/Properties"
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ChildProductID { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int QuantityStart { get; set; }
        public int QuantityEnd { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region "Constructor(s)"

        #endregion

        #region "Methods"

        #endregion
    }
```

In the controller action, I am simply trying to map the changed `PriceTier` properties:

```
public ActionResult EditChildProduct(AddEditChildProductModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return PartialView("AddEditChildProduct", model);

            ChildProduct childProduct = productService.GetChildProductByID(model.ID);
            AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<AddEditChildProductModel, ChildProduct>(model, childProduct);
            UnitOfWork.Commit();

            return ListChildProducts(model.ProductID);
        }
```

And I am getting this error:

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
```

When stepping into the action, the models/entities are mapped correctly, I don't get it!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-prop)

Comment: My guess would be because your ViewModels have ID properties that this call `AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<AddEditChildProductModel, ChildProduct>(model, childProduct);` is setting those ID values to null or 0.

Comment: @Paul - I was headed down that track as well, but stepping into the action shows the models are mapping to the entities correctly. Weird!

Comment: @Eranga - Similar, but I am not replacing the collection rather just trying to update properties on the entity. I load the object graph first from the db, then just change the properties, so???...

Comment: @Sam automapper will replace `PriceTiers` collection making some `PriceTier` objects orphans. You need to manually delete the items that are removed from the collection

Comment: @Eranga - OK, so AutoMapper replaces the whole collection as it is a property on the `AddEditChildProductModel` instead of going into the `PriceTiers` collection and changing the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eranga is right. I'm guessing your productService does not call AsNoTracking on the ef context before returning the ChildProduct. If not, this means what it returns is still attached to the context. When automapper does its thing, it replaces the whole collection, which can orphan the attached child entities that were not part of the form submission. Since the orphans don't have a non-null foreign key, they must be deleted from the context before calling SaveChanges. If they are not, you get this infamous exception.

On the other hand, if your productService calls AsNoTracking on the context before returning the entity, it will not track changes, and will not try to delete any orphaned items that do not exist in the collection created by automapper.

Comment: I have the same problem, and wouldn't there be a way to make automapper update the collections instead of replacing them? Or better yet, a way to allow me to define how to map two collections based on their types (i don't want to do it every time I call CreateMap for the types I want to handle)?