# MVC 3 detached entity saving related children properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, ado.net, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

Problem:

I need to save an updated detached EF object to the database.

The deatched entity is created through binding the base entity, then

```
  foreach child ...
     entity.children.add(child)
```

I add an Array of child entities that I also get from bind in controller.

What I want, is for the old entity to be completely replaced by the new entity, this means:

```
entity.property => update (easy)
entity.child => delete old child if not exists in the new,
                update if already exists (easy),
                or add if it doesnt exist already
```

What I have so far:

```
items tempitem = new items() { id = item.id };
_context.items.Attach(tempitem);
_context.items.ApplyCurrentValues(item);
foreach (var itemchild in item.children)
{
    childEntity tempchild= new childEntity () { parentid = item.id };
    _context.childEntity.Attach(tempchild);

    _context.childEntity.ApplyCurrentValues(itemchild );
}
```

This lets me update base entity fine, and also update any existing entities fine.

It doesnt let me delete old entities - tried doing an

```
item.children.Clear()
```

but nothing happens, and also when I try to add a new child entity (that was bound to the detached) - nothing happens either.

This can't be too hard, can it? I'm thinking of turning to NHibernate where things seem less bloated and more straightforward but powerful...

Comment: I don't know what's going on here. I had seen your comment below my answer and wrote my own comment below it (saying that I didn't delete any answers (I can't delete answers) and that here was no answer at all when I answered yesterday). Now both comments are gone. I don't know why. I guess you downvoted because you were angry somehow, believing that I did delete other answers. I only can tell you, I just wrote my answer and that's all I did.

Comment: I've brought this to Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114513/174063. They say that here are no deleted answers. If you are absolutely sure that you have submitted your own answer here and that here were other answers as well, you should describe this on Meta as a possible bug.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the reaction then, I thought it was your doing. Clearly the comments were also deleted so something is very wrong. I will also register with meta and pursue this when I have a bit more time.

Comment: It's possible that the *comments* have been deleted by a moderator. But moderators can't delete *answers* in a way that they are invisible for users with >10k reputation (that's what they explained to me on Meta). But here are no answers other than my own, also no deleted answers. That's the weird thing. If you have submitted an answer then something is wrong.

Comment: I see, there were 2 answers actually, one by me and one also very good answer but it wasn't complete

Answer (score 0):

Basically you must load the original object graph from the database (parent *and* all children, using `Include` for example), otherwise EF cannot know which children are new and which have been deleted. You have to add or delete the children then by comparing the loaded original child collection with the current collection in your detached entity.

An example how to do that is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540956/270591