# Entity framework, referential integrity constraint violation occurred error on updating entity from disconnected area

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have below model

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public virtual string OrderNo {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<OrderItem> Items {get;set;}
}

public class OrderItem
{
    [Key]
    public virtual string ItemNo {get; set;}
    public virtual string ParentItemNo {get;set;}
    public virtual string OrderNo {get;set;}

    public virtual OrderItem ParentItem {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<OrderItem> ChildItems {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<ItemProperty> ItemProperties {get;set;}
    public virtual Order Order {get;set;}
}

public class ItemProperty
{
    [Key]
    public virtual string PropertyNo {get; set;}
    public virtual string ParentPropertyNo {get;set;}
    public virtual string OrderItemNo {get;set;}

    public virtual ItemProperty ParentProperty {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<ItemProperty> ChildProperties {get;set;}
    public virtual OrderItem OrderItem {get;set;}
}
```

I'm running on disconnected area (with service our disconnected from the Entity Framework context)

1. I create a order and save to database

client:

```
service.CreateOrder(new Order() { OrderN="fksjdf1" });
```

server:

```
using(EfDbContext context = new EfDbContext())
{
    context.Orders.Add(order);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

1. I need to add one or more OrderItems to previously added order

client:

```
var order = service.GetOrder("fksjdf1");

var item1 = new OrderItem();
item1.ItemNo="i1";
item1.Order=order;
item1.OrderNo=order.OrderNo;
item1.ItemProperties.Add(new ItemProperty()
    PropertyNo="p1",
    OrderItem = item1
})
order.Items.Add(item1);

var item2 = new OrderItem();
item2.ItemNo="i2";
item2.Order=order;
item2.OrderNo=order.OrderNo;
item2.ItemProperties.Add(new ItemProperty()
    PropertyNo="p2",
    OrderItem = item2
});
item2.ItemProperties.Add(new ItemProperty()
    PropertyNo="p3",
    OrderItem = item2
})
order.Items.Add(item2);
service.UpdateOrder(order);
```

server:

```
using(EfDbContext context = new EfDbContext())
{
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = context.Entry(order);
    if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        // ERROR
        context.Set<Order>().Attach(order);
    }

    dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Error: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Why I see this error? Why I not update this entity?

How can i use entity framework from disconnected area?

EDIT 1:

```
public Order GetOrder(string orderNo)
{
using (EfDbContext context = new EfDbContext())
            {
                context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                var order = context.Orders
                    .Include(o => o.OrderItems
                                      .Select(z => z.ItemProperties
                                                       .Select(y => y.ChildProperties)))
                                                       .Where(o => o.OrderNo == orderNo)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code for service.GetOrder()? Using your code above, it doesn't produce an error (unless you're doing something like change the OrderNo for the order you retrieved, that's not shown)

Comment: @Mark Oreta, I shared my GetOrder function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have this error because you don't set `OrderItemNo` in `ItemProperty`, like so:

```
var item1 = new OrderItem();
item1.ItemNo="i1";
item1.Order=order;
item1.OrderNo=order.OrderNo;
item1.ItemProperties.Add(new ItemProperty {
    PropertyNo="p1",
    OrderItem = item1,
    OrderItemNo = item1.ItemNo // = "i1"
});
order.Items.Add(item1);

// and the same for item2
```

When the order gets attached to the context, related order items and item properties get attached as well. The navigation property `OrderItem` of `ItemProperty` refers to an entity with a key you supplied (`"i1"`), but the foreign key `OrderItemNo` doesn't have this key value. That's the inconsistency the exception is complaining about.

**Edit**

Unfortunately it is not that easy to update a detached object graph in the database. Setting the state of an entity to `Modified` only marks this entity as `Modified` and no related entity.

Your `GetOrder` method makes things complicated because you are eagerly loading already existing items and more related stuff to the client, then add new `OrderItem`s on client side and send this new modified object graph back to the server. On server side you now have the problem that you must handle the already existing items differently (don't insert them into the database) than the new items (insert them into the database). To do this, you need to detect which items are old and which are new. If you don't transport some flag in the entities themselves that would indicate if the entity is new or not, you must query the database again and compare the object graph loaded from the DB with the detached object graph sent from the client. A general sketch how it can be done is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540956/270591 (That's only for a parent with child collection. If grandchild collections are involved - like in your model - it is getting more complex.)

In my opinion you can simplify the whole procedure if you would not only have this global `service.UpdateOrder(order)` method that tries to handle all possible changes in the object graph but also some specialized methods that leverage the knowledge you have about the change of the graph - in this case a specialized method for adding new `OrderItem`s to an existing order. It could look like this:

```
var order = service.GetOrder("fksjdf1");

var newOrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();

var item1 = new OrderItem();
item1.ItemNo="i1";
item1.OrderNo=order.OrderNo; // leave the Order property null
item1.ItemProperties.Add(new ItemProperty { PropertyNo="p1" });
newOrderItems.Add(item1);

// the same for item2
newOrderItems.Add(item2);

service.AddNewOrderItems(newOrderItems);
```

And the service method would be:

```
public void AddNewOrderItems(List<OrderItem> newOrderItems)
{
    using(EfDbContext context = new EfDbContext())
    {
        foreach (var newOrderItem in newOrderItems)
            context.Set<OrderItem>().Add(newOrderItem);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't that be set when he sets the Relationship, since he's adding the entity to item1.ItemProperties?

Comment: @MarkOreta: I don't think so. On client side he is just building a POCO object graph with no context support. On server side he is attaching that object graph to the context. I don't think that EF will adjust the FK property because it cannot know what is correct: The FK value or the related entity? I think that is what the exception means.

Comment: @Slauma, I tried to add OrderItemNo, code not throw an exception on "context.Set<Order>().Attach(order);" line but nothing change on my database, EF cannot handle my changes.