# does entity framework 5 support object state tracking out of the box for disconnected entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

Does the EF5 support object state tracking out of the box for disconnected entities or do we have to write our own implementation of it.

If so, are there any good reference examples out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self tracking entities (STEs) seem  to be the thing you want. Ther used to be [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a3ac10a5-9365-4096-bb58-d9a1ba71db8f) template, but it seems Microsoft is not so fond of STEs anymore. They advise you to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj613668) though. They explain [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613924) why.

Comment: But it doesn't track properties. If I'm doing an update, it will update every single column in my table

Comment: That's pretty much the opposite of *change tracking*. How do you know that `Password` has been modified? *Change tracking* would mean that EF knows it so that you don't have to mark properties as `Modified` manually.

Comment: @Slauma It could have rescued him from using STEs :)

Comment: An alternative rescue would be to answer the question in the title just with "No." :)

Comment: But not when you want to use Code-First :) But seriously, I don't understand what they are saying under the second link. There is the Lerman/Miller approach to put an `EntityState` flag into the POCOs. This would be indeed client side change tracking, but it's not out-of-the-box and it requires to set and manage this flag on the client. They say "that's not an easy task, use the other approaches". The other approaches are WebAPI and WCF Data Services. How do they provide change tracking? The way I know is merging changes into the original which is "manual change detection", but not "tracking".

Comment: For me all this feels like they want to have the cake and eat it too. They want slim POCOs but full fledged change tracking. And besides, if you're not coding something that must handle tons of updates a second, updating the whole entity doesn't kill you.

Comment: But I see your point. I guess their point is, if you don't really really need it, use the WebAPI or WCF Data Services approach. But if you do, don't be surprised if the road's a little bumpy

Comment: Updating the whole entity works as long as you only have scalar properties to update. As soon as relationship changes get involved (like adding, removing, changing items in child collections) it's getting hairy. I'm still using an approach like this for relationship updates in disconnected scenarios (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5540956/270591) which isn't really change "tracking" and far from being out-of-the-box but a lot of code to write instead. I don't think the alternatives have been improved with EF 5.