# How to update relational database TABELS?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 4.0. I am facing problem while updating data in the database. I am getting this exception :

> *An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.*
>   *The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.*

I am working on the relational database. The following are 3 entities and there relation :

```
         1    to   *        1   to    *
Ceremony -----------> Menu ------------> CourseOption
```

Everything works fine, if I update the ceremony which already contains the `Menus` and `CourseOptions`. The problem comes when we insert new `Menu` and `CourseOption` entry in the ceremony at the time of update. Than I got the above mention exception.

**C# code to update existing ceremony**

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutCeremony(int id, Ceremony ceremony)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && id == ceremony.Id)
    {
       db.Entry(ceremony).State = EntityState.Modified;

       try
       {
           db.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
       {
           return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
       }

       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ceremony);
    }
    else
    {
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

How can I get rid of this problem? Please help

**EDIT**

Today i spend a whole day in this, i read a lot of articals and stackoverflow question. I found that `once a product is fetched from the Context, the context is keeping track of it` so that why instead of using :

```
db.Entry(ceremony).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I used

```
db.Entry(db.Ceremonies.Find(ceremony.Id)).CurrentValues.SetValues(ceremony);
```

Now by doing this change the exception gone and Ceremony entity properties are changing properly. But the ceremony related Menus entry and CourseOptions entry are not updating. Please give me suggestion guys. I am absolutely new in EF.

Comment: hey guys, the question is too difficult Or it is not clear, if later is the case than please let me know

Comment: You must change the question name!!

Comment: So, when you create a new `Ceremony`, you add new `Menu`s and `CourseOtion`s, or are they preexisting?

Comment: yes, at the time of creating new ceremony user can add Menu and course options, but if user want to add these (Menu and courseoption) later that he can do this while editing the ceremony. But the problem occure when we add new menu at the time of updating the existing ceremony

Comment: So it's not failing when you create a new `Ceremony`? It's actually impossible to see what's happening to `ceremony` before it's passed to `PutCeremony`. What I'm fishing for is what happens where you add those `Menu`'s.

Comment: Yes when i add new ceremony , than it adds properly without any issue, probelm comes only at the time of updating the existing ceremony

Comment: If you take a `Ceremony` from `db` and update it (let's say it has a `Name`) with a change in `Name` and store that change, do you then get in trouble? Work from the simplest and make your way toward the code you want.

Comment: No if i update the Ceremony entity properties than there is no trouble with that, trouble occure when i change the Menus property array (Navigation property to Menu entity). If i add new Menu object Or delete any existing that the changes do not take place in the database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18713/discussion-between-tom-rider-and-heki)

Answer (score 1):

Updating a detached object graph can be very difficult. (An example with only one child collection is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540956/270591 If you have a grand child collection it is even more complex.)

There is no generic approach or a simple method like setting the state to `Modified` (it only marks scalar properties as changed) and hoping it would store all the object graph changes.

The details to consider to implement such an update:

- Does the user *create* new menus when a menu is added to the ceremony or does he only establish a relationship between the ceremony and an *existing* menu?
- Does the user *delete* an existing menu when a menu is removed from the ceremony or does he only release a relationship between the ceremony and the menu, but the menu should be still existing in the database (the FK must be nullable then)?
- Can the user change (scalar) menu properties in your view or can he only add menus to a ceremony or remove them without changing the menus themselves?
- The same questions apply to the grandchild collection `CourseOptions` of each `Menu`.

For the (relatively simple) case that a user in your specific ceremony Edit view...

- can modify scalar properties of the ceremony
- can remove existing menus from a ceremony that should be deleted from the database when they are removed and the related `CourseOptions` should be deleted as well and cascading delete for that relationship is enabled in the database
- can create and add new menus to a ceremony that should be inserted into the database
- cannot change scalar properties of existing menus
- cannot add `CourseOptions` to an existing `Menu` and cannot delete them from a `Menu`
- can add new `CourseOptions` to an new `Menu` (and the `CourseOptions` should be inserted together with the new menu)
- cannot change scalar properties of an existing `CourseOption`

...the code would look like this:

```
var ceremonyInDb = db.Ceremonies.Include(c => c.Menus)
    .Single(c => c.Id == ceremony.Id);

db.Entry(ceremonyInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(ceremony);

foreach (var menuInDb in ceremonyInDb.Menus.ToList())
    if (!ceremony.Menus.Any(m => m.Id == menuInDb.Id))
        db.Menus.Remove(menuInDb);

foreach (var menu in ceremony.Menus)
    if (!ceremonyInDb.Menus.Any(m => m.Id == menu.Id))
        ceremonyInDb.Menus.Add(menu);

db.SaveChanges();
```

If some of the restrictions do not apply (i.e. the user can do more complex modifications in your view) the code will be more complex. But the basic idea is to load the object graph (root and children with `Include` and possibly grand children with `Include(...Select(...))`) from the database, compare that original graph with your new detached graph and apply changes to the original graph according to the differences to the new graph.