# Issue while updating the entry in the relational tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issue with updating database entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116764/issue-with-updating-database-entity)

I am working on the relational database with Entity FrameWork - 4.0. I am totally new for Entity FrameWork. I have 3 tables in my database with following relations :

```
         1   to   many       1   to  many
Ceremony -------------> Menu ------------> CourseOption
```

The problem is while updating the existing ceremony in the database. Suppose the `Ceremony` which i am going to update contains `1 menu` and `1 courseoption`. If i change the existing Menu and CourseOption property value than it works fine. Changes take place to the database correctly to the database.

**Main Problem** -> But if i add new Menu and CourseOption Or delete existing Menu and CourseOption than there will be no effect to database for this change.

`C#` code to update entry in the database :

```
db.Entry(ceremony).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

What i am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

For adding we have to write code like

```
db.Entry.Add(ceremony);
db.SaveChanges();
```

For Deleting We have to write like

```
db.Entry(ceremony).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```