# EF5 - Update the whole Entity, not the simple propertys

Tags: entity-framework-5, dbcontext

like this:

```
var Person = context.Persons.Find(10);
Persons UpdatedPerson = new Persons ({...});
Person = UpdatedPerson;
context.SaveChanges();
```

But the Context is 'unchanged'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var Person = context.Persons.Find(10);
Persons UpdatedPerson = new Persons ({...});
context.Entry(Person).CurrentValues.SetValues(UpdatedPerson);
context.SaveChanges();
```

`UpdatedPerson` must have the same key value (`10`) as `Person`. This will update all scalar and complex properties of `Person` but not entities related by navigation properties of `Person`.

Comment: Thats the way - thx. But how can I update the whole related properties?

Comment: @user2273950: You must load the related entities and then update them one-by-one. An example for a child collection is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro/5540956#5540956