# Linq query delete record from child table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I using code first ASP.NET C#. Trying to delete records from the child table in one to many relationship where 
`LoginBackEnds` is parent table and `AccessProviders` child table.

`LoginBackEnds` table has the following fields:
UserId,
UserLastName,
UserFirstName,

`AccessProviders` table has the following fields:
AccessId,
ProviderId,
LoginBackEnd_UserId (Foreign Key of UserId in `LoginBackEnds` table)

Any suggestion for delete statement using linq query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the Entities to remove if you have not already got them:

```
// Get the AccessProviders to delete
IQueryable<AccessProviders> accessProviders = context.LoginBackEnds.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId).AccessProviders;

// Delete AccessProviders
foreach(AccessProvider accessProvider in accessProviders)
{
    context.AccessProviders.DeleteObject(accessProvider);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

If you want to know the difference between `DeleteObject()` and `Remove()`, see my [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject).