# Fix 'The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint' error with code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 website with EntityFramework Code First. In my site, I have a `Restaurant` model with the following code:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //....
    public virtual IList<RestaurantType> Types { get; set; }
}
```

And the code for the `RestaurantType` is:

```
public class RestaurantType
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to delete the `restaurant` from context, I get the following error:

`The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.RestaurantTypes_dbo.Restaurants_Restaurant_ID". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-Test-20131111052251", table "dbo.RestaurantTypes", column 'Restaurant_ID'.
The statement has been terminated.`

I have data in production and I want to handle this as silently as possible. I tried the following code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < restaurant.Types.Count; i++)
            {
                var type = restaurant.Types[i];
                db.RestaurantTypes.Remove(type);
                restaurant.Types.Remove(type);
            }

            db.Restaurants.Remove(restaurant);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But I get the same error. I checked the database and there's no row with the restaurant ID. I even tried this:

```
        var list = db.RestaurantTypes.Where(t => t.Restaurant == null || t.Restaurant.ID == restaurant.ID);
        foreach (var ib in list)
        {
            db.RestaurantTypes.Remove(ib);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
```

It didn't work either. Is there a way for me to fix this with C# code?

Comment: Why has a restaurant a list of restaurant-types? Can it be of multiple types? Also, why does a restaurant-type has a reference to a restaurant?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the restaurant has a list of types, yes. Think of it as some kind of category. For instance a restaurant can be both Italian and Indian! Our system needs it. At first the reference to `restaurant` wasn't available. I just added that to write the last snippet. (check if the `Restaurant` field is `NULL`) I get the error no matter if it's there or not.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your model, *Remove* might not actually delete the row in RestaurantTypes. Try using *DeleteObject* instead (see [Entity Framework .Remove() vs. .DeleteObject()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject)). Also to be sure that the deletion of Restaurant is not happening before the deletion of all RestaurantTypes, try commiting the changes after deletion of all RestaurantTypes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < restaurant.Types.Count; i++)
{
    var type = restaurant.Types[i];
    db.DeleteObject(type);
    restaurant.Types.Remove(type);
}
db.SaveChanges();

db.DeleteObject(restaurant);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Also, on a side note (this has nothing to do with your error message): Aren't the relationships in your database model backwards. If a Restaurant can have one or many RestaurantTypes, you should have a references from the Restaurant to the RestaurantTypes. That means you need an additional table that holds the relationships (e.g. RelRestaurantRestaurantType):

```
---------------                      ------------------                          ------------------ 
|             |                      | Rel            |                          |                |
| Restaurant  | <-- Restaurant_ID -- | Restaurant     | -- RestaurantType_ID --> | RestaurantType |
|             |                      | RestaurantType |                          |                |
---------------                      ------------------                          ------------------
```

The way you are doing it, each Restaurant would have it's own copies of types. E.g. let's say you have a type "Chinese" and you are having 100 chinese restaurants. Then you would end up with 100 "Chinese" entries in your table RestaurantType.

Answer (score 0):

dispute the logic you have ( Restaurant and Restaurant Type), the Restaurant should be child of Restaurant Type.

what you are trying to do is a cascade delete
to get this, you should have keys in both tables

```
public class Restaurant{
    public Restaurant()
    {
        Types=new List<RestaurantType>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id{get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Name{get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<RestaurantType> Types{get;set;}
}

public class RestaurantType{
   [Key]
   public int Id{get;set;}
   [Required]
   public string Type{get; set;}
   public int RestaurantId{get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("RestaurantId")]
   public Restaurant Restaurant{get;set;}    
}
```

and your code will execute correctly
but be sure that your logic is correct, actually as what i know the restaurant has only one type and not many

regards

Comment: Actually, I don't think much of a difference in your code. The only change is that you've added the `ForeignKey` attribute which EF infers from class definition. Just to be sure, I can test it. Are you sure it's the reason I get this error?

Comment: i forgot to mention, sometimes you need to make the entity state to deleted,by this you are ensuring that the EF will delete the rows by using : db.Entity(type).State=EntityState.Deleted; ... hope it will help you