# Entity Framework: What happens with related entity when updating/deleting main entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship

I have an entity (A) which has a related entity (B). When I load A I want to load B automatically.

I have set the following in the OnModelCreating():

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasRequired(o => o.CreatedByAdministrator).WithMany().HasForeignKey(o => o.CreatedBy);
```

Besides I have set:

```
public DbSet<A> As { get; set; } 
public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
```

When I load a list with entities A - I say:

```
context.As.Include("CreatedByAdministrator").ToList();
```

It seems to work perfect. But I want to make sure - that when I save/update/and delete A - it should never affect the related B. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Delete**

Set `WillCascadeOnDelete` on your mapping to false.

```
ModelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasRequired(o => o.CreatedByAdministrator).WithMany().HasForeignKey(o => o.CreatedBy).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**Save and update**

If you haven't edited a property in your related entity, it won't update/save anything. 
If you did edit something, you can always set that property to `null`.

Or you can set the state of that object to `Unchanged`.

```
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get(fetch data) from A then you can  retrive data of related entity

**Get/Fetch**

```
e.g.
var  model  = a.tolist()

in view 
Model.b.yourproperty
```

**Update/Save**

If You want to update and save then you have to write update or save functionality.otherwise manually it not affect to your related property.

**Delete**

plz check fundamental [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject)

also agree with @Loetn for delete.