# Conditional Record Delete in a Loop

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Can someone explain how to conditionally delete objects from an EF result set?

Here is my code

```
var newClubKitOrders = from q in db.NewClubKitOrders where q.NewClubId == ncbId select q;
if (newClubKitOrders.Any())
{
    foreach (NewClubKitOrder order in newClubKitOrders)
    {
        if (checkedStatus == true)
        {
            order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            //delete the row (order.delete())
        }
    }

   newClubKitOrders.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject

Comment: What's the problem? The delete method, the loop?

Answer (score 4):

You can't delete 'order'  in “foreach” loop. So try “for” loop.

Comment: This seems to not cause any warnings inside foreach() in VS but not sure if it actually deletes yet: var success = newClubKitOrders.Remove(order);

Comment: @Slinky It'll compile, but when you go to run it it'll complain that the enumeration had changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DeleteObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.deleteobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Like this:

```
        else
        {
           newClubKitOrders.DeleteObject(order);
        }
```

[Here is a good SO on some other options and how it all works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject)

Edit: Also yes, use a for loop, I didn't notice what you were iterating over. Thanks Rashmin Javiya!

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, i have copied list in another list to be on safe side. temp list is just to traverse but actual transaction take place on original list

```
var newClubKitOrders = from q in db.NewClubKitOrders where q.NewClubId == ncbId select q;

if (newClubKitOrders.Any())
{
    var TempnewClubKitOrders = newClubKitOrders.ToList();

    for(int i=0; i< TempnewClubKitOrders.Length; i++)
    {
        if (checkedStatus == true)
        {
            newClubKitOrders[i].OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            db.NewClubKitOrde.DeleteObject(newClubKitOrders[i]);
        }
    }

   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Error: "Cannot apply indexing to linq expression.." I guess I cannot use array indexer for some reason - seems odd since it was converted to a list

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
var newClubKitOrders = from q in db.NewClubKitOrders where q.NewClubId == ncbId select q;

if (newClubKitOrders.Any())
{
    foreach (NewClubKitOrder order in newClubKitOrders)
    {
        if (checkedStatus == true)
        {
            order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            db.NewClubKitOrders.Remove(order);
        }
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```