# Entity Framework DbContext .Remove(obj) vs .Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF Code first. a simple model:

```
  item { public int Id {set; get;},... ,ICollection<ItemImages> {set; get;} }

    itemImages { 
         public int Id {set; get; },
         public int ItemId {set; get; }
          , ... ,
         public Item Item  {set; get; }
      }

ItemConfig:EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
{
 //some config statement;
 //...
// mark child delete when parent delete: waterfall delete.
 HasRequired(rs => rs.ItemCat).WithMany(rs => rs.Items).HasForeignKey(rs => rs.ItemCatId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

when delete entity by **Remove()**, it delete item and related child (item images records) well.

```
_db.Item.Remove(DeleteThisObj);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

but when mark it to delete:

```
_db.Entry(DeleteThisObj).State = EntityState.Deleted;
_db.SaveChanges();
```

get error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework .Remove() vs. .DeleteObject()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject)

Answer (score 15):

If you really want to use Deleted, you'd have to make your foreign keys nullable, but then you'd end up with orphaned records (which is one of the main reasons you shouldn't be doing that in the first place). So just use `Remove()`

[ObjectContext.DeleteObject(entity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.deleteobject.aspx) marks the entity as Deleted in the context. (It's EntityState is Deleted after that.) If you call SaveChanges afterwards EF sends a SQL DELETE statement to the database. If no referential constraints in the database are violated the entity will be deleted, otherwise an exception is thrown.

[EntityCollection.Remove(childEntity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337024.aspx) marks the relationship between parent and childEntity as Deleted. If the childEntity itself is deleted from the database and what exactly happens when you call SaveChanges depends on the kind of relationship between the two:

If the relationship is optional, i.e. the foreign key that refers from the child to the parent in the database allows NULL values, this foreign will be set to null and if you call SaveChanges this NULL value for the childEntity will be written to the database (i.e. the relationship between the two is removed). This happens with a SQL UPDATE statement. No DELETE statement occurs.

If the relationship is required (the FK doesn't allow NULL values) and the relationship is not identifying (which means that the foreign key is not part of the child's (composite) primary key) you have to either add the child to another parent or you have to explicitly delete the child (with DeleteObject then). If you don't do any of these a referential constraint is violated and EF will throw an exception when you call SaveChanges - the infamous "The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable" exception or similar.

If the relationship is identifying (it's necessarily required then because any part of the primary key cannot be NULL) EF will mark the childEntity as Deleted as well. If you call SaveChanges a SQL DELETE statement will be sent to the database. If no other referential constraints in the database are violated the entity will be deleted, otherwise an exception is thrown.

A thing worth noting is that setting `.State = EntityState.Deleted` [does not trigger automatically detected change.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/06/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-12-automatically-detecting-changes.aspx)

Comment: so Remove() mark childs state records in context  as Deleted but Entry(obj).state = EntityStae.Deleted don't? acctually i want water fall delete

Comment: @Mohammadreza You can think of it this way, `Remove` affects record and relationships while `delete` affects only record at hand.