# Why entity Framework does not accept the command DeleteObject?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public JsonResult DeleteAjax(int id)
    {
        Product data = (from product in _db.Product
                        where product.Id == id
                        select product).SingleOrDefault();
        _db.Product.DeleteObject(data);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Json("Product deleted succsesfully");
    }
```

VS does not recognize DeleteObject(). Why not?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject

Comment: I try with Remove() does not work

Comment: What do you mean by "does not accept", what error are you getting? No one can help you if you don't ask clearly, give us a clear error message, in full and exactly as it is written

Comment: As @RonanThibaudau points out, it is unclear what exactly is happening. Are you getting a compile error for `_db.Product.DeleteObject(data);`, an exception, or what does "not recognize" mean?

Comment: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MVCProject.API.Product>' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteObject' and no extension method 'DeleteObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MVCProject.API.Product>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)