# Delete selected entity object from gridview,where foreign key table block it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

These are the tables `Employee`, `EmployeeTicket`, `Ticket` in my SQL Server database:

http://i62.tinypic.com/709q50.png

And this is how its seen in my Entity Framework model

http://i57.tinypic.com/30w9fup.png

As you see my foreign key table becomes a navigation property and it's OK I found a way to use it.

```
// Use a LINQ expression to find the selected product.
int selectedID = (int)GridViewTicketHistory.SelectedDataKey.Value;
var matches = from p in entities.Employees
              where p.ID == selectedID
              select p;

// Execute the query and return the entity object.
Employee emp = matches.Single();

// Delete the entity object.
entities.Employees.DeleteObject(emp);

// Commit the changes back to the database.
entities.SaveChanges();

editCustomerTicket();
```

The problem is I get an error:

> The DELETE statement is in conflict with the constraint REFERENCE "FK_EmployeeTicket_Employee". The conflict occurred in the table "dbo.EmployeeTicket", column 'ID' database "TrackUser"

Which means I can't delete ID from `Employee` and I think I should first delete the ID in foreign key table. How can I achieve that? Or is there any simple change I can do to get rid of this error?

Comment: u can try to make EmployeeTicket ID as allows NULL

Comment: for more info take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject

Comment: Thx for the answer the link you give should solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

u can try to make EmployeeTicket ID as allows NULL depends on how set the colums properties

for more info take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723626/entity-framework-remove-vs-deleteobject)