# C# EF6 Rollback changes, EntityState.Unchanged error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

```
// Rollback changes

switch (entry.State)
{
    case EntityState.Added:
        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
        break;
    case EntityState.Modified:
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
        entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        break;
    case EntityState.Deleted:
        entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        break;
}
```

This code is used after `EF6 SaveChanges()` exception

My scanrio, I insert some values and delete old one then I get an exception. My data should be preserved because of rollback and web site should work normally. But I get this exception in "EntityState.Unchanged" in sector "EntityState.Modified:"

> Message=The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed
>   because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable.
>   When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key
>   property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support
>   null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key
>   property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated
>   object must be deleted.   Source=EntityFramework

Why I can not change DB context back to previous state?

EDIT:

How I delete dependencies?

```
workReport.sepapayments.Remove(sepaPayment);

workReportAccountSettlement.workreports.Remove(workReport);
```

Comment: You need to remember previous values of your entites somehow if you need to undo changes in the given DBContext. But unless you change the data int the database using `SaveChanges()` you can dispose the DBContext and create a new DBContext from database values.

Comment: I can not so simply dispose it. I am using Ioc.var context = unitOfWork.Context as DbContext;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the entities from collections

```
workReport.sepapayments.Remove(sepaPayment);

workReportAccountSettlement.workreports.Remove(workReport);
```

try to delete them

```
myDBContext.Entry(sepaPayment).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;  

myDBContext.Entry(workReport).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
```

Or you can

```
myDBContext.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(sepaPayment);
```

[See also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17726414/2224701). The reason you get this exception is because FK is non-nullable, the UML association between those entites (classes) is a composition, so you need either completely delete the entity or change the FK of the related entity first.

Answer (score 1):

the data you are trying to remove have dependent child objects and you have foreign key relation ship setup. therefore you can not delete/add.

Have a look on items you are adding and removing and ensure you have valid entities.

I would split your implementation into two

1st

delete existing items (ensure the dependent child items are removed before you remove parent or use cascade)
 - if you are using cascade be careful what are you deleting

2nd

add new items once deleting works

Comment: That I can do, but first problem here is that I can not rollback my data. I updated my question how I delete dependencies