# Entity Framework Core 3.1 Nested Collections Remove Objects Linq Expression Fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My question is smiler to this, where I want to remove items from the nested collection.
[Entity Framework Core, deleting items from nested collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331850/entity-framework-core-deleting-items-from-nested-collection)
can you please help me find out what I'm doing wrong?
thank you.

My DB update function looks like this:

```
public async Task<Step> Update(short id, Step entity)
        {
            entity.Id = id;
            var context = _formulaDBContext;
            var missingNodes = context.Nodes.Where(i => i.StepId == entity.Id).Except(entity.Nodes);
            context.Nodes.RemoveRange(missingNodes);
            var t = Task.Run(() => context.Set<Step>().Update(entity));
            t.Wait();
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }
```

I'm doing the same as the accepted answer but it fails with below exception:

```
    System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred. (Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<Node>
    .Where(i => (int)i.StepId == (int)__entity_Id_0)
    .Except(__p_1)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.)
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Formula.UI.RecepiDataViewModel.<EditStep>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Users\gje\source\repos\formula\Formula.UI\ViewModels\RecepiMaker\RecepiDataViewModel.cs:line 62
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Formula.UI.RecepiDataViewModel.<<-ctor>b__7_1>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\gje\source\repos\formula\Formula.UI\ViewModels\RecepiMaker\RecepiDataViewModel.cs:line 46

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    Formula.UI.StepDataService.Update(short, Formula.Models.Step) in StepDataService.cs

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<Node>
    .Where(i => (int)i.StepId == (int)__entity_Id_0)
    .Except(__p_1)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.
```

Here is my models:

```
 public class Step : BaseModel
        {
            public Step()
            {
                Nodes = new List<Node>();

            }
            public short RecepiId { get; set; }

            public short PVTagId { get; set; }
            public Operator Operator { get; set; }

            public TagMetaData PVTag { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public Activity Activity { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("StepId")]
            public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

        }

        public class Step : BaseModel
        {
            public Step()
            {
                Nodes = new List<Node>();

            }
            public short RecepiId { get; set; }

            public short PVTagId { get; set; }
            public Operator Operator { get; set; }

            public TagMetaData PVTag { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public Activity Activity { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("StepId")]
            public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

        }

        public class BaseModel
        {
            public short Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `missingNodes`  query to something like this:

```
var missingNodes = context.Nodes
    .Where(i => i.StepId == entity.Id)
    .Except(context.Nodes.Where(n => entity.Nodes.Select(ei => ei.Id).Contains(n.Id)));
```

or:

```
var missingNodes = context.Nodes
        .Where(i => i.StepId == entity.Id && !entity.Nodes.Select(ei => ei.Id).Contains(i.Id));
```

In short the issue is that EF can't pass local collection of complex types to query during translation into SQL and execution (at least in some cases).