# Do I need to create a DBSet for every table? So that I can persist child entities?

Tags: ef-code-first

My EF5 model

```
public Layout()
{
   public int Id {get;set}
   public BindingList<Column> Columns {get;set}
}
public Column()
{
   public int Id {get;set}
   public string Name {get;set}

   [Required]
   [ForeignKey("LayoutId")
   public virtual Layout Layout {get;set}
   public int LayoutId {get;set}

}
```

In my context I only need to specify

```
DBSet<Layout> Layouts {get;set}
```

I dont need to specify DBSet Columns for the database to create the way I want it with both tables.

Also I am happy in my code to only ever access columns via the layout object
However i cant figure out how to persist the layout object with its columns correctly.

This  [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro)  describes how to save parent objects with children, but it would require me to create a DBSet Columns property in my context. Do I really have to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can get by without having a DBSet in the context if instead of using

```
Context.Columns.Remove(col)
```

I use

```
Layout.Columns.Remove(col)
Context.Entry(col).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```