# Delete an item from DataGridView and Entity Framework context

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I can't seem to get this working. This is in an event handler:

```
Private Sub DeleteItemIcon_Click(ByVal sender As DataGridView, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse Not e.ColumnIndex = sender.Columns("delete_item").Index Then Return
    sender.DataSource.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
    context.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

Shouldn't removing the item from the BindingSource propagate the changes to my entity context? I'm getting this exception:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro)

Comment: the difference is the `BindingSource`. I can call `BindingSource.AddNew()`, and the new object gets persisted to the database no problem. Why not the reverse?