# MVC: Updating One to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-many, updates

I have a one-to-many relationship defined below

```
public class Student{
   [key]
   public string Id{get; set;}
   public string name{get; set:}
   public virtual List<Enrollment> Enrol{get; set;}
}

public class Enrollment{
  public int Id{get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("student")]
  public String StudentId{get; set;}
  Public string ISC{get; set;}
  public virtual Student student{get; set;}

}
```

I have a form allowing me to edit a Student entity including adding or removing some enrollments. When saving this data after the form is submitted, does the enrollments get updated too, or do I have to update the enrollments separately? Ideally, should the enrollment by deleted and then re-inserted or just updated (and doing inserts only when there are more new items than there are existing ones)?

Comment: Are you using ASP-MVC? EF? (MVC is just a design pattern, not a technology and LINQ is not automatically EF, it can be LINQ-to-objects as well.)

Comment: I re-tagged your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to walk the graph. EF doesn't update relationships automatically.

This response has a good example of insert/update delete child objects:
[The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro/5540956#5540956)

There is also a good extension method that adds graph walking functionality:
https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff