# Entity Framework - Remove object with foreign key, preserving parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have have the following models:

```
public class Company
{
    //Primary key
    public string ID { get; set; } 

    //Foreign key
    public int? LogotypeID { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Logotype
{
    //Primary key
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    //Foreign key
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }
}
```

How do I delete the logotype from the Company table, **without** removing the company row?

Using:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.remove(v=vs.113).aspx
DbSet.Remove(Logotype) thows the following exception:

```
{"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_dbo.Companies_dbo.Logotypes_LogotypeID\". The conflict occurred in database \"ShipReg\", table \"dbo.Companies\", column 'LogotypeID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

Any ideas?

Br,
Tim

Comment: in Logotype table is company id is the foreign key?

Comment: Are you using Data-Migrations? If so do you have cascading deletes set to true?

Comment: @Rudresh. yes, CompanyId is the foreign key.

Comment: @Marc. We are not using Data-Migrations at the moment. I'm not sure if cascading deletes is default.

Comment: Whats the relationship between company and Logotype ? One to Many or one to one or many to one

Comment: @PratikBhoir. It is one to one and one to zero (it's not mandatory for a company to have a Logotype).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add a virtual property in company like

```
public class Company
{
    //Primary key
    public string ID { get; set; } 

    //Foreign key
    public int? LogotypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Logotype Logotype {get;set;}
}
```

and then

```
dbContext.Entry<Company>(company).State=EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.Entry<Logotype>(company.Logotype).State=EntityState.Deleted;
```