# The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, graphdiff

I get following error during update with EF:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Is there any **general** way to find which foreign-key properties cause above error?

**[Update]**

For one case following code cause above error(I worked in a disconnected environment, so I used `graphdiff` to update my objects graph), when it wants to run `_uow.Commit();`:

```
public void CopyTechnicalInfos(int sourceOrderItemId, List<int> targetOrderItemIds)
{
  _uow = new MyDbContext();
   var sourceOrderItem = _uow.OrderItems
          .Include(x => x.NominalBoms)
          .Include("NominalRoutings.NominalSizeTests")
          .AsNoTracking()
          .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == sourceOrderItemId);


   var criteria = PredicateBuilder.False<OrderItem>();
   foreach (var targetOrderItemId in orderItemIds)
   {
      int id = targetOrderItemId;
      criteria = criteria.OR(x => x.Id == id);
   }
   var targetOrderItems = _uow.OrderItems
                              .AsNoTracking()
                              .AsExpandable()   
                              .Where(criteria)
                              .ToList();

  foreach (var targetOrderItem in targetOrderItems)
  {
        //delete old datas and insert new datas 
        targetOrderItem.NominalBoms = sourceOrderItem.NominalBoms;
        targetOrderItem.NominalBoms.ForEach(x => x.Id = 0);

        targetOrderItem.NominalRoutings = sourceOrderItem.NominalRoutings;
        targetOrderItem.NominalRoutings.ForEach(x => x.Id = 0);
        targetOrderItem.NominalRoutings
                       .ForEach(x => x.NominalTests.ForEach(y => y.Id = 0));
        targetOrderItem.NominalRoutings
                       .ForEach(x => x.NominalSizeTests.ForEach(y => y.Id = 0));
       _uow.OrderItems.UpdateGraph(targetOrderItem, 
                                   x => x.OwnedCollection(y => y.NominalBoms)
                                         .OwnedCollection(y => y.NominalRoutings, 
                                          with => with
                                         .OwnedCollection(t => t.NominalTests)));
   }
   _uow.Commit();
}
```

Comment: can't you narrow down your code and post it here? I (as well as some others) have never encountered this kind of exception, so we need more context to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Hopeless: I mean generally how can I find foreign-key properties that causes the error. but if need I can post my code, too.

Comment: @masoud , I found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858491/entity-framework-remove-object-with-foreign-key-preserving-parent

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In Entity Framework you can work with *foreign key associations*. That is, a foreign key to another object is expressed as a pair of two properties: a primitive foreign key property (e.g. `NominalRouting.OrderItemId`) and an object reference (`NominalRouting.OrderItem`).

This means that you can either set a primitive value or an object reference to establish a foreign key association. If you set one of them, EF tries to keep the other one in sync, if possible. Unfortunately, this may also give rise to conflicts between primitive foreign key values and their accompanying references.

It's hard to tell what exactly happens in your case. However, I *do* know that your approach of "copying" objects from one parent to another is... not ideal. First, it's never a good idea to change primary key values. By setting them to `0` you make the object look like new, but they aren't. Secondly, you assign the same child objects to other parent objects many times. I *think* that, as a consequence, you end up with a large number of objects having a foreign key *value* but not a *reference*.

I said "copying", because that's what you seemingly try to achieve. If so, you should properly clone objects and `Add` them to each `targetOrderItem`. At the same time, I wonder why you (apparently) clone all these objects. It looks like many-to-many associations are more appropriate here. But that's a different subject.

Now your actual question: **how to find the conflicting associations?**

That's very, very hard. It would require code to search through the conceptual model and find properties involved in foreign key associations. Then you'd have to find their values and find mismatches. Hard enough, but trivial when compared to determining when a *possible* conflict is an *actual* conflict. Let me clarify this by two examples. Here, a class `OrderItem` has a required foreign key association consisting of properties `Order` and `OrderId`.

```
var item = new OrderItem { OrderId = 1, ... };
db.OrderItems.Add(item);
db.SaveChanges();
```

So there's an item with `OrderId` assigned and `Order` = null, and EF is happy.

```
var item = db.OrderItems.Include(x => x.Order).Find(10);
// returns an OrderItem with OrderId = 1
item.Order = null;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Again, an item with `OrderId` assigned and `Order` = null, but EF throws the exception "The relationship could not be changed...".

(and there are more possible conflict situations)

So it's no enough to look for unmatched values in `OrderId/Order` pairs, you'd also have to inspect entity states and know exactly in which combination of states a mismatch is not allowed. **My advice: forget it, fix your code.**

There's one dirty trick though. When EF tries to match foreign key values and references, somewhere deep down in a tree of nested `if`s it collects the conflicts we're talking about into a member variable of the `ObjectStateManager`, named `_entriesWithConceptualNulls`. It's possible to get its value by doing some reflection:

```
#if DEBUG

db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); // Force EF to match associations.
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
var objectStateManager = objectContext.ObjectStateManager;
var fieldInfo = objectStateManager.GetType().GetField("_entriesWithConceptualNulls", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var conceptualNulls = fieldInfo.GetValue(objectStateManager);

#endif
```

`conceptualNulls` is a `HashSet<EntityEntry>`, `EntityEntry` is an internal class, so you can only inspect the collection in the debugger to get an idea of conflicting entities. For diagnostic purposes only!!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you said " it's never a good idea to change primary key values" and "you should properly clone objects ...", the result is the same in this 2 cases, why do you think the second is better?

Comment: Generally it works best when entities are separately identifiable object so EF can track them properly. I don't know what you mean by "this 2 cases". If this means you tried something else, we better look at it in another question. This question focusses on how to find (not to fix) FK errors.

Comment: Many thanks for the dirty trick! Without it it was difficult for me to detect the entities involved in the conflicts.

Comment: The ditry trick was great - helped me narrow down my problem significantly. Thank you!!