# Entity Framework marks foreign key relation as null even though it is not

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two abstract classes, with two respective derived classes, as follows (simplified, of course):

```
public abstract class Activity 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectActivity : Activity
{
}

public abstract class Schedule
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    protected List<Activity> _entries;
    public List<Activity> Entries
    {
        get { return _entries.OrderBy(e => e.StartTime).ToList(); }
        set { _entries = value; }
    }

    protected SiteSchedule()
    {
        _entries = new List<Activity>();
    }
}

public class ProjectSchedule : Schedule
{
}
```

These classes are present in the database using a TPH (Table per Hierarchy) construction. So I have an `Activity` table and a `Schedule` table, both with a discriminator column.

When I try to save a very straightforward relation like this:

```
ProjectSiteSchedule schedule = new ProjectSchedule();

context.Schedules.Add(schedule);
context.SaveChanges();

ProjectActivity activity = new ProjectActivity()
{
    ScheduleID = schedule.ID,
};

context.Activities.Add(activity);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get the following error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

The navigational properties are set as a one-way relation on purpose. In the Fluent API I've defined the relation as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Entries)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ScheduleID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

It's a very strange thing, because `ScheduleID` is properly set on the `ProjectActivity` object. However, when for testing purposes I changed `ScheduleID` to a nullable field, the `ProjectActivity` could be saved, but with `ScheduleID` set to `null` in the database even though it was set in the code.

It seems like Entity Framework changes the `ScheduleID` property from a given integer to a `null` value when it tries to save it. I tried the 'dirty trick' given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32803161/970589) to check what the state of the entity was before it would try to save it, but even as it returns the entity as an `_entriesWithConceptualNulls` entry, the `ScheduleID` was properly set.

Comment: Your `List<Activity> Entries` getter looks like trouble... please check whether the problem persists when you return the list field without change.

Comment: Could not reproduce with your example, what version of EF are you on? Also, please post the migration to create these tables, as mine added and saved a valid value in the `ScheduleId`.

Comment: @grek40 You are right. The `.ToList()` call causes the error. Which is strange, as `_entries` itself is a list. So if I pass a list without change everything works, but if I order the list, recast it as a list, and return it, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Kazu You are not recasting it, you are returning a *new* list instance. EF is using the collection property to track added children and of course fails because it adds the child to a newly created list (i.e. no where). Never do that in model classes.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ofcourse. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the navigation property `Entries`

```
protected List<Activity> _entries;
public List<Activity> Entries
{
    //don't create a new list in getter!
    //get { return _entries.OrderBy(e => e.StartTime).ToList(); }
    get { return _entries; }
    set { _entries = value; }
}
```

Because the getter is returning a new list (`.ToList()`), the underlying list in `_entries` will never be updated this way. As a result, EF can't maintain a consistent state of entities and throws an error.

Change the getter to return the stored list without change `get { return _entries; }`. If you need an ordered List, just order in the using code, add some getter method or add a not-mapped property for usage in client code.

```
[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<Activity> OrderedEntries
{
    get { return _entries.OrderBy(e => e.StartTime); }
}
```