# C# ASP.Net - Error when trying to delete data from table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have table Player and table Statistic and other tables that are not important in this question.
Table Player has PK Player_ID and it is FK in table Statistic. The relationship between these tables is one-to-many (one player can have more statistics).

Here is the code:
GenericRepository(I have created it to have unique class for CRUD methods)

```
public async Task<int> Delete<T>(Guid id) where T : class
{
        try
        {
            T entity = await Get<T>(id);
            Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
            return await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

PlayerRepository(for managing operations on Player table)

```
public async Task<int> Delete(Guid id)
{
        try
        {
            var player = await GenRepository.Get<Player>(id);
            if (player == null)
            {
                return 404;
            }
            else
            {
                return await GenRepository.Delete(player);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

PlayerService(connection between repository and controller in WebAPI)

```
public async Task<int> Delete(Guid id)
{
        try
        {
            return await PlayerRepository.Delete(id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

PlayerController

```
[HttpDelete]
    [Route("deleteplayer")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Delete(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            var Finder = Mapper.Map<PlayerView>(await PlayerService.Get(id));
            if(Finder == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Player doesn't exist in database.");
            }

            var Response = await PlayerService.Delete(id);
            var profile = "../../../app/pictures/FootballFanAppPictures/" + Finder.Club_ID.ToString().ToUpper() + "/profiles/" + id.ToString().ToUpper() + ".png";
            var details = "../../../app/pictures/FootballFanAppPictures/" + Finder.Club_ID.ToString().ToUpper() + "/" + id.ToString().ToUpper() + ".png";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(profile))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(profile);
            }
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(details))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(details);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Response);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
        }
    }
```

Entity models:

-database models

```
 public partial class Player
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Player()
    {
        this.Statistic = new HashSet<Statistic>();
    }

    public System.Guid Player_ID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid Club_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Shirtnmbr { get; set; }

    public virtual Club Club { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Statistic> Statistic { get; set; }
}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Statistic
{
    public System.Guid Statistic_ID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid Player_ID { get; set; }
    public int Goals { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
    public int FoulsFor { get; set; }
    public int FoulsAgainst { get; set; }
    public int ShotsTotal { get; set; }
    public int ShotsGoal { get; set; }

    public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
}
```

-domain models (used in repository)

```
public class PlayerDomain : IPlayerDomain
{
    public Guid Player_ID { get; set; }
    public Guid Club_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Shirtnmbr { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IStatisticDomain> Statistic { get; set; }
}
public class StatisticDomain: IStatisticDomain
{
    public Guid Statistic_ID { get; set; }
    public Guid Player_ID { get; set; }
    public int Goals { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
    public int FoulsFor { get; set; }
    public int FoulsAgainst { get; set; }
    public int ShotsTotal { get; set; }
    public int ShotsGoal { get; set; }
}
```

-view models (used in controller)

```
public class PlayerView
{
    public Guid Player_ID { get; set; }
    public Guid Club_ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Shirtnmbr { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StatisticView> Statistic { get; set; }
}
public class StatisticView
{
    public Guid Statistic_ID { get; set; }
    public Guid Player_ID { get; set; }
    public int Goals { get; set; }
    public int Assists { get; set; }
    public int FoulsFor { get; set; }
    public int FoulsAgainst { get; set; }
    public int ShotsTotal { get; set; }
    public int ShotsGoal { get; set; }
}
```

Every class is in a separate file. I use database first approach so i got .edmx file along with database models. Database is created in SQL Server Management Studio.

I can update Player but when I try to delete it i get this error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I have searched various answers on google and stackoverflow but I couldn't find an answer that solves my problem

Comment: From exception message it looks like Player has relation to another table where you are using player id

Comment: @user7479651,Please refer following links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325473/ef6-0-the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675411/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro

Comment: @GhulamMohayudin I know that. I don't know how can I delete Statistic entries when I delete specific player.

Comment: @VIGNESHARUNACHALAM I have already seen these answers. The problem is that in these answers they are manipulating directly with db context and I'm not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you call this line:

```
var Response = await PlayerService.Delete(id);
```

You are going to need to retrieve a list of your statistics that are assigned to the player you are trying to delete.

Then loop trough each of the statistics and delete those from your database first.

```
var stats = Finder.Statistic.ToList();

if(stats != null && stats.Any())
{
   foreach(var stat in stats)
   { 
      //retrieve your stat record here from the database
      //check that the stat record is not null
      //delete your stat record here
   }
}
```

Then you should be able to delete your player record as there will no longer be references to it.

OR

You could just set ON DELETE CASCADE to true, but you need to be careful that you fully understand what all will be deleted on player deletion.

Comment: OMG. So simple. I will try that now. It makes sense and I couldn't get that. Thank you :)

Comment: If I do it like this: `var x = await StatisticService.Delete(stat.Statistic_ID);` I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: Its hard to know what this is referring to when I cant debug the code. Are you sure the StatisticService is initialised? Did you check that stat is not null before passing it into the Delete?

Comment: Also when you map your player record to your player view record are the stats being mapped also?

Comment: I get stat with complete data and it is not null. To me it doesn't makes sense why it is showing that error. How do you mean are stats being mapped also? They are mapped separately like this:

`CreateMap<Statistic, IStatisticDomain>().PreserveReferences().ReverseMap().PreserveReferences();
            CreateMap<Statistic, StatisticDomain>().PreserveReferences().ReverseMap().PreserveReferences();

CreateMap<Player, IPlayerDomain>().PreserveReferences().ReverseMap().PreserveReferences();
            CreateMap<Player, PlayerDomain>().PreserveReferences().ReverseMap().PreserveReferences();`

Comment: Is StatisticService initialised?

Comment: yes, it is using interface. `protected IStatisticService StatisticService { get; set; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153135/discussion-between-bad-dub-and-user7479651).

Comment: I dont know why you would be getting that error then. Have you tried debugging line by line to see what object is null?

Comment: When the code gets to line `var x = await StatisticService.Delete(stat.Statistic_ID);` then it fires that error. stat is not null.

Comment: See that makes it look like StatisticService has not been initialised if stat is not null. If you debug again and on that hover over StatisticService and double check its not null.

Comment: Yes, I see it is null. But why? I have set it like this: `protected IStatisticService StatisticService { get; set; }`

Comment: I have found error. So stupid. I forgot to add it in constructor (singleton pattern) -.-
Now I will fix that and try again to debug.

Comment: Well I have managed to delete a player, but in first button click it deletes statistic and throws an error from question for deleting player. In second click it deletes player with no problem.

Comment: You may have to retrieve the player record again before deleting it as changes have been made to its relations. Give that a go.

Comment: I have done it with two modals in two .html files with help of two components (I use Angular). First deletes statistic, second deletes player. Your answer is accepted as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see Statistic deletion on Player delete in your code.
Before you can delete a Player, you need to delete all Player related Statistics first. If there is any left, a player will fail on delete operation.

Comment: Is there any way of deleting Statistics along with Player when I'm deleting Player entry?

Comment: If you want this happening automatically, you can set "ON DELETE CASCADE" flag on FK relationship. Or in Player.Delete() method you need to delete manually all related Statistics, list of which will be in related entities list called by name of your FK.

Comment: I have read about cascade deleting. I have set that type of relationship in SSMS on Player table, recreated models and there was no change. I believe that I have set up cascade deleting in a wrong way.

Comment: In DataBase first scenario as you described, the cascade deleting happens on a server side. Does it still fail on Player delete after you set "ON DELETE CASCADE" flag?

Comment: I have set up cascade delete as shown in picture in answer above and updated models in visual studio. Do I need to do anything else to make cascade delete to work? Is my way of setting up cascade delete the right way?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct way of doing it. Still getting the same error on Player.Delete()?

Comment: I have managed to make it work like @BadDub suggested but I can't delete player and statistic in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Set PrimaryKey and Foreignkey Relationship :according to @Bad Dub suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Do I need to do anything else besides that in Visual Studio project?

Comment: No don't need to do anything in Visual Studio project.Just update Entity Frame Work Model.