# Log by Error: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: entity-framework, logging

Why EF6 can't give me more informations by this error?

I tried with db.Database.Log but this gives me nothing. I want only to know which field coused this Issue, because I dont see it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some more informations I get from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675411/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro?rq=1) question:

```
#if DEBUG

db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); // Force EF to match associations.
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
var objectStateManager = objectContext.ObjectStateManager;
var fieldInfo = objectStateManager.GetType().GetField("_entriesWithConceptualNulls", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var conceptualNulls = fieldInfo.GetValue(objectStateManager);

#endif
```

conceptualNulls is a HashSet, EntityEntry is an internal class, so you can only inspect the collection in the debugger to get an idea of conflicting entities. For diagnostic purposes only!!! (thanks to [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold))