# How should a one to many relationship be managed in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, one-to-many

I am having trouble understanding at a fundamental level how a one to many relationship should be managed in Entity Framework. In my application I have two tables, `DISPLAY_MASTER`, and `DISPLAY_ITEMS`. Their relationship is like so:

DISPLAY_MASTER.DISPLAY_ID **1----->*** DISPLAY_ITEMS.DISPLAY_ID

Entity Framework organizes this really intuitively. I am left with a strongly typed `DISPLAY_MASTER` object that has an `ICollection` property called `DISPLAY_ITEMS`.

My confusion lies within how to save the `DISPLAY_ITEMS` collection back to the database. In my application I am reading in all of the `DISPLAY_ITEMS` for the particular `DISPLAY_MASTER` using LINQ into a `List<DISPLAY_ITEMS>` object called `_displayItems`. This is then bound to a `DataGrid` for editing using MVVM. The user can edit existing `DISPLAY_ITEMS`, delete existing `DISPLAY_ITEMS`, or add new `DISPLAY_ITEMS` using the `DataGrid`. My binding works perfectly and these changes are reflected in `_displayItems`. Once it comes time to save is where I stop feeling confident in my code. When the user clicks save I am setting the `DISPLAY_MASTER`'s `ICollection` like so:

```
_displayMaster.DISPLAY_ITEMS = _displayItems;
```

Is this the proper way to be working on an Entity Framework collection? Or should I be binding the `DataGrid` directly to the `_displayMaster.DISPLAY_ITEMS` object? Or some other method? The reason I am not confident is because if I try to validate the `_displayMaster.DISPLAY_ITEMS` entity using:

```
DbEntityValidationResult validationResults = _context.Entry(_displayMaster.DISPLAY_ITEMS).GetValidationResult();
```

I get an error saying 'List1' is not part of the collection, which obviously doesn't seem right.

Any advice or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

- If you disconnect the entities from their database context when you bind them to the grid (i.e. if you dispose the context after loading the entities and create a new context when it comes to save the changes) then it's not so easy. You will have to load the master including the old items from the database, merge the changes into that collection based on your new edited collection from the grid and then save the changes. An example how to do that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540956/270591).
- If you keep the entities attached to the context you have loaded them into while the user is editing it's much easier if you just directly bind `_displayMaster.DISPLAY_ITEMS` to the grid because EF is then able to track all the changes you are performing on the collection and update the object graph automatically to the database when you call `SaveChanges`.

Since you tagged the question with WPF you *might* have the second option (depending on your application's architecture). In web applications for example the second option doesn't exist at all because all editing happens in a browser which is disconnected of course from the context.

Comment: I do have the second option, however I am unable to bind to the entity directly because it is of the type `ICollection`. When I go to edit the record in the `DataGrid` I get an error saying 'EditItem' is not available. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @user3043546: I suggest that you ask a separate question about this follow-up problem. It sounds more like a WPF binding subject than an EF problem. I can't help you here, I'm not familiar enough with WPF.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, you are right. By the way I did more research and your second solution was the way to go.