# How to get new record ID when creating audit trail?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```js
public override saveChanges(){
    var changeList = tracker.detectChange();
    foreach(var change in changeList){
        switch(change.state){
            case ADD: ...
            case MODIFIED: ...
        }
    }
      
      
    base.saveChanges();
}
```

I have the above code structure (only pseudo code for illustrating idea) of creating audit trail when save changes.

The only problem is that, I cannot get the newly added record ID as `saveChanges` has not yet been called, however if I call `saveChanges` ahead, then the tracker could not track the changes as ALL state of the entries will become `unchanged`!

So how can I still track the changes while getting the new record ID ?

**EDITED**

Reason why I have to get the new record ID, as you may guess, is to save an audit trail record in DB. For some reason, it has to be an XML document which stores the entity's ID, original value & new value (and some other stuff which is out of concern).

Say for a newly added "Item" in Item table in DB,  I have to store a new audit trail record which at least showing this new "Item" 's ID,  original value (which is null), and new value.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve with the new record Id?

Comment: Do you use `EntityFramework`?

Comment: @wonderbell Please see edited.

Comment: You can save the entities added / modified / deleted in separate list inside your `for loop`. After `saveChanges` is called, all entities would be updated with new Ids. You can use your lists then to create the desired XML.

Comment: @wonderbell That's what I am trying to do, but it becomes another problem: how to deep copy an DbEntityEntry object(s).   As after you call savechanges, all these objects will become "unchanged" state, you cannot determine which is added /modified/ deleted if you do not deep copy ahead

Comment: @StepUp Yes, I am using EntityFramework 6

Comment: please, show your model classes what is the relationship? `One-to-Many`?

Comment: @StepUp How come it is related to model classes? It is savechange() in general context level, for all model classes. Yea there are all kinds of relationship(1-* , 1-1, * - *) but I do not think that is related...

Comment: @StepUp Thanks for advice, I will try to clarify the question once I get home

Comment: At first you clarify your question and you'll get more help. At second, when you have One-to-Many, then you should say to `EntityFramework` what you want with newly attached collections. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changed entities can be added to separate lists according to their state before the method `saveChanges` is called.

After `saveChanges` all entities would be updated with new Ids and the corresponding lists can be used to generate the audit logs.

```
public override saveChanges(){
    // gather audit data
    initialize List<Entity> addedEntities, modifiedEntities, deletedEntities
    var changeList = tracker.detectChange();
    foreach(var change in changeList){
        switch(change.state){
            case ADD: add to addedEntities
            case MODIFIED: add to modifiedEntities
        }
    }


    base.saveChanges();
    performAudit(addedEntities, modifiedEntities, deletedEntities);
}

function performAudit(...){
  generateXML(...);
  saveToDB(...);
  sendEmail(...);
}
```

Note: I have not tested if `deletedEntities` would still be valid, but they can anyway be audited before saveChanges as they already have an Id. But I hope you get an idea on how to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I get your idea, so even if the state of the entity is unchanged, I still can just loop addedEntities for those new records, etc.? I will try it, hope it works and will let you know

Comment: Thanks! It works, I use your idea and it works like a charm

Comment: Glad that it helped.