# Update table row and corresponding collection using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this class:

```
 public class General_File
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Small_File> Small_Files{ get; set; }    
}
```

and this is `Small_File` class:

```
public class Small_File
    {
        [Key] 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Parameter{ get; set; }
        public string Name{get; set;}  
        public int FileId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FileId")]
        public virtual General_File General_File{ get; set; }
    }
```

I want to modify a row in the `General_File` table, modify it, not add a new one, that includes the Small_Files collection corresponding to that row too, it will change too, but I'm not sure of how to deal with this in Entity Framework.... I've been trying with this code.. The  `local_generalFile.Small_Files` have already the same ids of the files in the table plus some new instances that should be saved in the Small_Files tables too generating its ids..., how can I update that row in General_File and its corresponding `Small_Files` collection?

```
 public void SaveFileToDatabase(string type)
        {                          
           General_File toModify = _ctx.General_Files.Include("Small_Files")
.Where(s => s.Type== type).OrderByDescending(s => s.id).FirstOrDefault();

               toModify.Small_Files = this.local_generalFile.Small_Files;
              _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The code above in the `SaveFileToDatabase` method is throwing an exception:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Comment: What will happen if the `FileId` property changed to `Nullable<int>`: `public int? FileId { get; set; }`? Also see this for similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro.

Comment: Any modifications should be performed on `toModify.Small_Files`, istead of `this.local_generalFile.Small_Files`. So It may be listened by entity-framework. Try it and let me know the result.

Comment: Actually you change the reference of `toModify.Small_Files` which EF has no any mechanism to listen actions (add / remove) on it.

Comment: Additionally `toModify.Small_Files = this.local_generalFile.Small_Files` assigns reference to `ICollection` inside `General_File` that doesn't have any EF data handling (create/update/delete) associated with it.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

Any modifications should be performed on `toModify.Small_Files`, instead of `this.local_generalFile.Small_Files`. So It may be listened by entity-framework
To let `EF` to listen add or remove operations on `toModify.Small_Files`:

```
 public void SaveFileToDatabase(string type)
    {                          
           General_File toModify = _ctx.General_Files.Include("Small_Files")
.Where(s => s.Type== type).OrderByDescending(s => s.id).FirstOrDefault();
               this.local_generalFile.Small_Files = toModify.Small_Files;

               // do stuff with this.local_generalFile.Small_Files

              _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```