# Removing an element of collection which is a field of model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have very simple models and I'd want to modify (remove) an element of
collection which is a property of one of them.

```
public class Student
{
   [Key]
   [Column(Order = 1)]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string SecondName { get; set; }
   public int DepartamentID { get; set; }
}

public class Departament
{
   [Key]
   [Column(Order = 1)]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

private void Remove(List<int> IDsOfStudentsToRemove)
{
    foreach (int id in IDsOfStudentsToRemove)
    {
       var Student = StudentContext.Students.Find(id);

       var Departament = DepartamentsContext
            .Departaments.Find(Student.DepartamentID);

       // That's what I'd want to achieve:
       // Remove student from Departament's Students collection
       // then remove student from Students Table

       Departament.Students.Remove(Student);
       StudentContext.Students.Remove(Student);
    }

    StudentContext.SaveChanges();
    DepartamentContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

But that's the error that I'm receiving

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation failed: The
>   relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
>   foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a
>   relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.
>   If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship
>   must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another
>   non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.'

Very similar thread:

[The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you simply delete the student (`StudentContext.Students.Remove(Student);`). If the cascade delete for the relationship is on, it will be automatically removed from department students.

Comment: @IvanStoev Unfortunely, probably I did something bad during modeling or I simply didnt create relations (cuz Im trying to figure it out) and it doesnt work like that :[