# Persist database changes with asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-database-first

I am a beginner in the field of IT, more particularly in the C # language, I use the ASP.Net MVC framework.

I am working on an online restaurant web application, I will be the administrator of the site, so it is I who manage any addition of restaurants or menus.

For the moment I am working on my two classes `Restaurant` and `Menu`, they are linked by a relation `1:n` and I use the database first approach.

So my ViewModel `Restaurant-Edit` has a collection of `Menu` while `Menu-Edit` has an instance of `Restaurant` in its code.

```
namespace RestaurantProjet3.Models
{
  public class MenuEditee
  {
    public int IdMenu { get; set; }

    public int fk_Resto { get; set; }
    public string NomPlat { get; set; }
    public int Prix { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Categories { get; set; }
    public byte?[] Photos { get; set; }

    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Here, the problem that arises is the following, I worked on the page of edition of the menus of my restaurants whose here is the code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit_Menu(MenuEditee menuEdit)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(menuEdit);
    }

    Menu menuBd = contexteEF.Menu.Single(m => m.IdMenu == menuEdit.IdMenu);
    menuBd = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<MenuEditee,Menu>(menuEdit,menuBd);

    contexteEF.SaveChanges();
    return null;
```

When I want to replace the data contained in my comic by those contained in my `ViewModel`, an exception occurs telling me that

> "System.InvalidOperationException: Operation failed: unable to modify
>   the relationship because one or all of the foreign key properties do
>   not accept null values. When a modification is made to a relationship,
>   a null value is assigned to the associated foreign key property. If
>   the foreign key does not support null values, a new relationship must
>   be defined, the non-null value must be assigned to the foreign key
>   property or the unassociated object must be deleted"

and I noticed when I put a breakpoint in my code, the restaurant instance contained in my `Menu-Edit` ViewModel returns a null value.

This is why when mapping its content in `Menu` which is in my database, one of the attributes of `Menu-Edit` is returned empty (the restaurant instance) which creates an exception.

What should i do to avoid errors and finally be able to persist my changes in the database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538974/the-relationship-could-not-be-changed-because-one-or-more-of-the-foreign-key-pro)

Comment: I don't have a reference handy, but generally speaking, using Automapper to go from view-model to database-model is a [bad idea](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code); you want to be specific about what fields you're updating.

Comment: no that did not solve my problem

Comment: I was just trying to edit one of the attributes of MenuEdit, for example the Price attribute